# Laravel connect to Azure SQL Data warehouse using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, database, azure, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and want to connect to a Azure Data warehouse using the implemented PDO database connection Laravel provides. I am using the following connection settings.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=tcp:srv.url.com,1433
DB_DATABASE=db-name
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

When I load the page I get a "could not find driver" error.

How is this possible? The drivers are build into Laravel rigth?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, any updates yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the PDO driver for sqlsrv manually, configure in PHP PDO_SQLSRV extension enabled by adding appropriate DLL file like `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll`, and which is only compatible with PHP running on Windows. You can refer to http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php for more info.

To connect to SQL server in PHP in Unix, you can use ODBC extension and [Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160).